# Coming up with explicit formula for $f_\ast$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $f:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$ is given by $f(z,w)=(z^3, w^2)$. What can be the explicit formula for $f_\ast$ then? Since $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$, can I say it is $f_\ast(z,w)=(z+3, w+2)$? How can I check if this formula is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. A homomorphism $f_* : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is determined by where it sends $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Thus, it's enough to check that $f_* (1,0) = (3,0)$ and $f_* (0,1) = (0,2)$ to confirm that $f_*(z,w) = (3z, 2w)$.

To check $f_*(1,0) = (3,0)$, it's enough to look at a representative. Let $\gamma : S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ be defined by $\gamma(t) = (e^{2\pi i t} , 0)$. Then $[\gamma] = (1,0)$. Now $f_*([\gamma]) = [f\circ \gamma]$. We have
$$
(f \circ \gamma)(t) = (e^{6\pi i t} , 0)
$$
At this point it depends on your course how you should finish the argument, but the point is that $(e^{6\pi i t} , 0)$ winds $3$ times around the first circle and $0$ times around the second circle. Thus $[f\circ \gamma] = (3, 0)$.

Comment: Thank you!  Could you show how to check the first one? I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Sure. I feel like this answer is not especially illuminating, so I might wait to accept until other answers come in.